# iOS: Get how fast user is moving

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm wanting to figure out if a user is not moving at all, walking, or running using the iPhone. I'm not trying to implement a pedometer. I just want to know around about if someone is moving briskly, slowly, or not at all. I don't need mph or anything like that.

I think the accelerometer may be able to do this for me, but I was wondering if someone  knows of any tutorials or example code that might be able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks to all that reply

Answer (score 4):

The accelerometer won't do you any good here - it will only capture changes in velocity.

Just track the current location periodically and calculate the speed.

Answer (score 0):

There are no hard thresholds for walking vs. running motion, so you will have to experiment a bit. The [AccelerometerGraph](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AccelerometerGraph/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code should get you started on how to get and interpret accelerometer data.

Answer (score 0):

The Accelerometer is good, but if the user has an iPhone 4 or iPad 2 you should use the gyroscope.

[CMMotionManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CMMotionManager) and [Event Handeling Guide - Motion Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW1)

Apple Documentation is the best example you can get!

Answer (score 0):

People have a different bounce in their step between walking and running which can be measured with the accelerometer, but this differs between individuals (what shoes they are wearing, what surface they are upon, what part of the body is attached to the iPhone etc.), and this motion can probably be imitated by shaking the iPhone just right while standing still.

Experiment by recording the two types of acceleration profiles, and then use some sort of pattern matching to pick the most likely profile candidate from the current recorded acceleration data.